# in Excel use name from namebox ( range ? ) in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

What I want to do is select a range `B2:B5`and give it a name, just above cells `A1` and `B1` there is a namebox and I type the name: "My_Test_Range" here and hit enter.

1. The word `Range` is this the official name for range as described above in Excel?

Then I want to loop trough the range `B2:B5` using `VBA` and do something like make all the cells to the right of the ranged cells 1.

2. How do I do the above?

I want to do this with the `named range`, because I find a name like "Options_For_Red_Car" or "Options_For_Blue_Car" much easier to read than `B2:B5` etc., especially if you get say a dozen such ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Range` is a very important object in the Excel object model. Here is one of probably thousands of references to information about ranges:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238(v=office.15).aspx

Seems like you like `named-ranges` which is good as they are very powerful and useful and if you're going to start playing with `vba` then you'll find them more and more useful.

To loop through the cells in a range you can do something like the following:

```
Sub loopThroughRangeCells()

Dim cell
For Each cell In Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:C6").Cells
    MsgBox cell.Address
Next

End Sub
```

Although really it is better to create object reference variables when doing something like the above and also to use a `named-range':

```
Sub loopThroughRangeCells()

Dim cell
Dim s As Excel.Worksheet                     '<<creates an object variable
Set s = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  '<<the object variable now references our target sheet

'<<using object variable and named range the following code is simplified

For Each cell In s.Range("helloWorld").Cells
    MsgBox cell.Address
Next

End Sub
```

In the above I've just done `MsgBox cell.Address` within the loop but you can change this to anything you like - you might like to experiment and try to change the cells to the right to 1.

In the above I've declared a `variant` typed variable `cell`. This is standard practice to call each member of the collection `cells` a `cell` even though no object cell exists in the object model. This is different than most collection like `worksheets` where it is a collection of an intuitive object `worksheet`

Comment: @ whytheq Hello whytheq, I tried the code and it works great I was looking for this van hours, well that makes me a real beginner I guess. There are some parts I dont understand though. When you do: "Dim cell" you make a variable but I dont get what you put in it.And the text "Each cell In" I understand what it must do as it is human readable text. But what if I want to change it to every cell of the first column, I wouldnt have a clue where to start and look for info to get me there. What is the best place to find this info? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @3xBla. Just practice and reading as many resources as you can find - I just Googled this phrase "looping through cells in column excel-vba" and got quite a few hits. Yes - in answer I've used the word "cell" but could have just used the letter "c". Try commenting out the line "Dim Cell" .... you should get an error. I'll add a bit more explanation to my answer.